# Why am I getting a null pointer when adding to the end of a linked list

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, linked-list

I am having problems with my add() method in my linked list implementation. It was working fine until I added the method, doubleInPlace(). It seems that the problem has something to do with how I have myTail implemented. Could someone provide any advice on how to solve this issue?

```
public void add (Object x) {
    ListNode temp;
    if(isEmpty()){
        myHead = new ListNode(x);
        myTail = myHead;
    }
    else{
    ListNode addNode = new ListNode(x);
    myTail.setNext(addNode);
    myTail = myTail.myNext;
    }
    mySize++;
}
```

Here is the full implementation of my linked list.

import java.util.*;
public class List implements Iterable{

```
private ListNode myHead;
private ListNode myTail;
private int mySize;
public List() {
    myHead = null;
    myTail = null;
    mySize = 0;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return myHead == null;
}

private static class ListNode {

    private Object myItem;
    private ListNode myNext;

    private ListNode (Object item, ListNode next) {
        myItem = item;
        myNext = next;
    }

    private ListNode (Object item) {
        myItem = item;
        myNext = null;
    }

    public void setNext(Object item){
        myNext = new ListNode(item);
    }

    public void setNext(ListNode node){
        myNext = node;
    }

    public ListNode getNext(){
        return myNext;
    }
    public void setItem(Object item){
        myItem = item;
    }

}

public Iterator iterator() {
    return new ElementIterator();
}

public class ElementIterator implements Iterator {
    ListNode p;
    int nextElement;
    int size;
    public ElementIterator() {
        p = myHead;
        nextElement = 0;
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        return nextElement < size();

    }

    public Object next() {
        Object next = p.myItem;
        if (nextElement < size()){
            next = get(nextElement);
            nextElement++;
        }
        return next;
    }

    public void remove() {
        // not used
    }
}

public String toString() {
    String rtn = "( ";
    for (ListNode p = myHead; p != null; p = p.myNext) {
        rtn = rtn + p.myItem + " ";
    }
    return rtn + ")";
}

// Return the number of items in this list ("length" in Scheme).
public int size() {
    return mySize;
}

// Return true if the list contains the object 
public boolean contains (Object obj) {
    for (ListNode p = myHead; p != null; p = p.myNext) {
        if (obj.equals (p.myItem)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Returns the element at the given position in this list.
public Object get (int pos) {
    if (pos < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException (
                "Argument to get must be at least 0.");
    }
    if (pos >= size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Argument to get is too large.");
    }
    int k = 0;
    for (ListNode p = myHead; p != null; p = p.myNext) {
        if (k == pos) {
            return p.myItem;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return null;
}

public void addToFront (Object obj) {
    myHead = new ListNode (obj, myHead);
    mySize++;
}

public boolean equals (Object obj) {
    List comp = (List) obj;
    ListNode comp_node;
    Object compare_node;
    boolean isEqual = false;
    int count = 0;
    if(size()!=comp.size()){
        return false;
    }
    if(obj.toString().equals(this.toString())){
        return true;
    }
    return isEqual;
}

/*public void add (Object x) {
    ListNode temp;
    if(isEmpty()){
        myHead = new ListNode(x);
    }
    else{
    temp = new ListNode(x);
    ListNode orig = this.myHead;
    for (; orig.myNext != null; orig = orig.myNext){
        //orig = orig.myNext;
    }
    //while (orig.myNext != null){
    //  orig = orig.myNext;
    //}
    orig.myNext = new ListNode(x);
    }
    mySize++;
} */

public void add (Object x) {
    ListNode temp;
    if(isEmpty()){
        myHead = new ListNode(x);
        myTail = myHead;
    }
    else{
    ListNode addNode = new ListNode(x);
    //myTail.myNext = new ListNode(x, null);
    myTail.setNext(addNode);
    myTail = myTail.myNext;
    }
    mySize++;
}


public void appendInPlace (List l) {
    if(isEmpty()){
        myHead = l.myHead;
        myTail = l.myTail;
    }else if(l.isEmpty()){
        return;
    }
    else{
        myTail.myNext = l.myHead;
        myTail = l.myTail;
    }
}

//remove all links that are equal to object a
public void remove(Object a){
    if (isEmpty()){
        return;
    }
    if (myHead.myItem == a){
        myHead = myHead.myNext;
        mySize--;
    }

    //loop through the nodes and if item equals a, set item to next item and ref to next's next
    ListNode p = myHead;
    ListNode lastNode;
    lastNode = new ListNode("");
    int tempSize = mySize;
    for (int i=0; i < tempSize - 1; i++){
        if (p.myItem == a){
            lastNode.setNext(p.myNext);
            mySize--;
        }
        lastNode = p;
        p = p.myNext;
    }

    //if tail is equal to item, delete last node
    removeTail(a);      
}

public void removeTail(Object a){
    if (myTail.myItem == a){
        ListNode temp = myHead;
        ListNode temp2 = myTail;

        if (mySize == 2){
            temp.myNext = null;
            myTail = temp;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i< mySize-2; i++){
            temp = temp.myNext;
        }

        temp.myNext = null;
        myTail = temp;
        mySize--;

    }       
}
public void doubleInPlace() {
    ListNode p = myHead;
    for (; p != null; p = p.myNext) {
        ListNode temp = new ListNode(p.myItem, p.myNext);
        p.setNext(temp);
        p= p.myNext;
    }
    myTail = p;
}

public void isOK(){
    boolean isOK = true;
    //Check size is ok
    int mySizeCheck = 0;
    ListNode temp = myHead;
    while (temp != null){
        temp = temp.myNext;
        mySizeCheck++;
    }
    if (temp.myItem != myTail.myItem){
        throw new IllegalStateException("The tail is not correct.");
    }
    if (mySize != mySizeCheck){
        throw new IllegalStateException("The size is not correct.");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: The heuristic for NullPointerExceptions is almost always the same: You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.  Note that if you've posted your NPE stacktrace and have indicated which line is throwing the exception, the two most important bits of information when figuring this out, then I seem to have missed it. Please help us out here.

Comment: The exception is thrown by 'myTail.setNext(addNode);' when I am testing my doubleInPlace() method. That is all that is shown in my failure trace.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question. My add worked before, but now when I have my doubleInPlace() method, it fails. I know it has to do with my myTail implementation, but do not know how to fix it. I have tried simply setting myTail.myNext = new ListNode(x, null), but that gives the same error.

Comment: Post your stack trace as @Hovercraft Full Of Eels suggested.

Comment: Yeah it is definitely a duplicate question. You're setting myTail to null after the for loop in your double in place method.

Comment: Note your loop only exits when p **is** null, and then you set p to myTail, guaranteeing that myTail will be null. Again, this question is just like all the thousands of NPE questions we see. You will want to learn the steps to debug this before asking yet another one.

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft. I didn't realize I was setting it equal to the next of the last element. I fixed it. @Lew Bloch However, how do I get the full stack trace? I only see the failure trace on the bottom left of my Eclipse IDE with the 3 things of my assertion test failure, add failure, and null pointer exception.